# partition on range a and b

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following table

```
EmpId   Date    StartOn EndOn
0001    2-Feb-17    590 599
0002    2-Feb-17    600 609
0003    2-Feb-17    610 619
0004    2-Feb-17    626 635
0002    2-Feb-17    630 639
0004    2-Feb-17    640 649
0005    3-Feb-17    630 639
```

and I want the output to be like this

```
EmpId   Date    StartOn EndOn   Overlapping Num
0001    2-Feb-17    590 599            0    1
0002    2-Feb-17    600 609            0    1
0003    2-Feb-17    610 619            0    1
0004    2-Feb-17    626 635            1    1
0002    2-Feb-17    630 639            1    2
0004    2-Feb-17    640 649            0    1
0005    3-Feb-17    630 639            0    1
```

here a sample of data

```
create table Data(
    EmpId nvarchar(4),
    Date date,
    StartOn int,
    EndOn int
  );

insert into Data(EmpId,Date,StartOn,EndOn)
values('0001','02 Feb 2017',590,599),
('0002','02 Feb 2017',600,609),
('0003','02 Feb 2017',610,619),
('0004','02 Feb 2017',626,635),
('0002','02 Feb 2017',630,639),
('0004','02 Feb 2017',640,649),
('0005','03 Feb 2017',630,639)
```

> **Requirements** : I want to know how many overlapping occurs between
>   `StartOn` and `EndOn` on given date and to sort these overlapping by the 
>   `StartOn`, for example `EmpId` ( 0004 overlaps with `EmpId` 0002 between range 626
>   and 639 ( overlap occurs between range 630 and 635), so `Overlapping` column
>   will hold  the number of overlaps and `Num` will hold the number of
>   order by `StartOn`

This what I tried

```
    ;with overlapping as(
    select a.EmpId,a.Date,a.StartOn,a.EndOn,count(b.EmpId) as Num
    from #Data a
    left join #Data b on a.Date = b.Date
    and a.StartOn<=b.EndOn and a.EndOn>=b.StartOn and b.EmpId<>a.EmpId
    group by a.EmpId,a.Date,a.StartOn,a.EndOn
)
select *,rank() over(partition by Date,Num order by StartOn) as Row
from overlapping
order by Date,StartOn,EmpId
```

I tried the `row_number` and `rank` but failed to get any desired result

Comment: Your query does not even compile; please edit your question.

Comment: Can't re-create your attempt, it doesn't match the sample data you provided.

Comment: @ZoharPeled i corrected it

Comment: It will work if I can row_number only the rows with Num>0, how to do this?

Comment: if one row have StartOn and EndOn as 600 and 700, and another row 610 and 620, then there is Overlapping  for those rows or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by adding the `iif` inside the partition

```
;with overlapping as(
    select a.EmpId,a.Date,a.StartOn,a.EndOn,count(b.EmpId) as Num
    from #Data a
    left join #Data b on a.Date = b.Date
    and a.StartOn<=b.EndOn and a.EndOn>=b.StartOn and b.EmpId<>a.EmpId
    group by a.EmpId,a.Date,a.StartOn,a.EndOn
)
select *,row_number() over(partition by Date,iif(Num=0,StartOn,Num) order by StartOn) as Row
from overlapping
order by Date,StartOn,EmpId
```

but i am looking for better solution

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to do this with `exists` rather than a self join.  Then, on top of exists, a cumulative sum to define the "groups" and then `row_number()`:

```
with d as (
      select d.*,
             (case when exists (select 1
                                from #data d2
                                where d2.StartOn <= d.EndOn and
                                      d2.EndOn >= d.StartOn and 
                                      d2.EmpId <> d.EmpId
                               )
                    then 1 else 0
              end) as IsOverlap
      from #data d
     )
select d.*, row_number() over (partition by grp order by StartOn) as num
from (select d.*, sum(IsOverlap) over (order by StartOn) as grp
      from d
     ) d;
```

However, I'm not 100% sure this meets your needs.  What should the results be when there are more overlaps?  What happens if an `EmpId` overlaps with him/her self?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  EmpId, 
            [Date], 
            StartOn, 
            EndOn,
            ISNULL((
                SELECT 1
                FROM Data t2 
                WHERE t2.EmpId <> t1.EmpId
                AND t2.[Date] = t1.[Date]
                AND t2.StartOn < t1.EndOn
                AND t2.EndON > t1.StartOn
            ), 0) As Overlapping
    FROM Data t1
)

SELECT  EmpId, 
        [Date], 
        StartOn, 
        EndOn,
        Overlapping,
        ISNULL(NULLIF(Overlapping, 0) + LAG(Overlapping) OVER (ORDER BY [Date], StartOn, EndOn), 0) As Num
FROM CTE
```

With the sample data you provided, the result is:

```
EmpId   Date        StartOn     EndOn   Overlapping     Num
0001    02.02.2017  590         599     0               0
0002    02.02.2017  600         609     0               0
0003    02.02.2017  610         619     0               0
0004    02.02.2017  626         635     1               1
0002    02.02.2017  630         639     1               2
0004    02.02.2017  640         649     0               0
0005    03.02.2017  630         639     0               0
```

[Live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/IFQU89652)

Comment: Your query failed with adding this record to the list " `('0006','02 Feb 2017',631,639)")`

Comment: Well, that was not in the sample data... anyway, I saw you answered your one question, so I guess my answer is no longer needed...